# Do I need to realloc after memmove when remove an element from dynamic array?

Tags: c, arrays, pointers, memory

I'm working on a ArrayList implementation in C. ArrayList stores pointers (void*), that means ArrayList is a dynamic array of pointers. Here how I remove an element from ArrayList:

```
typedef struct
{
    void* ptr; // pointer of array (beginning)
    int length; // pointer count
}ArrayList;

void ArrayList_Remove(ArrayList *list, int index)
{
    memmove(
        list->ptr + (sizeof(void*) * index),
        list->ptr + (sizeof(void*) * (index + 1)),
        (list->length - index) * sizeof(void*)
    );
    list->length--;
    // Do I need to realloc list->ptr to free space?
    // list->ptr = realloc(list->ptr, list->length * sizeof(void*));
}
```

As I commented in code, do I need to realloc `list->ptr` or `memmove` will do it?

Comment: note :  It is not possible to apply pointer arithmetic to the type of `void *`.

Comment: @BLUEPIXY How to get pointer by offset then? Maybe array of pointers (`void**`) ?

Comment: It is no problem if you use the extension of the GCC. Normally it will cast to `char*`. yes, if `void **p = malloc(size * sizeof(void*));`

Comment: if use `void**`, (Except for the `sizeof(void*)`) `sizeof(void*) * index`  --> `index`

Comment: You mean `ptr[index]` is equal to `ptr + (sizeof(void*) * index))` right?

Comment: `&ptr[index]` is equal to `ptr + index`

Comment: A common pattern is to track both the length and the allocated length. When you add an element, you only need to reallocate if the length and allocated length are equal. When you remove an element, you have the option to reallocate or not, and typically you would only reallocate of the allocated length was a lot greater than the used length.

Comment: @DavidSchwartz Currently, it doesn't reallocate after remove because we may (most likely) re-use this memory block again. I implemented another function named `ArrayList_FreeUnusedSpace()` and it does reallocating if wanted. Otherwise, empty space still in our use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First thing: memmove is not involved in memory allocation at all. It just does what it should, move (potentially overlapping) parts of the memory.

In your example it is not absolutely necessary to realloc the array. It mainly depends if so much elements are removed that there would be a relevant amount of free space for reusage. If you feel that this is indeed relevant, your realloc-statement below looks correct. But keep in mind, that the unallocated space might not be usable at all if just a few elements are deleted per array due to heap fragmentation issues.

Comment: I see what you mean :) Also, thanks for pointing **memory fragmentation**.

Answer (score 1):

`memmove()` will not free any memory.

You could use `realloc()`, or maybe just leave the extra space there in case you need to add/insert an item. That would need an extra member in your struct to keep track of the allocated size.

Also, if you plan to **dynamically add** or **insert** items, you might want to grow your buffer in larger chunks to prevent having to call `realloc()` each time. Normally this is done in powers of two up to a certain size (for example 16 - 32 - 64 -- 1024). After that, expand the buffer with a fixed size each time.